# Uploading file to file system

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have seen so many working [examples](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABackToBasicsCaseStudyImplementingHTTPFileUploadWithASPNETMVCIncludingTestsAndMocks.aspx) of File uploading with MVC.

However, I want to follow a different approach such that, I want a little abstraction as follows:

I want to introduce a FileService, and inject that to the controller as a dependency. Let the service upload the file and return me a UploadedFile object.

A problem I am having right now is to upload to correct place/directory in file system or application root.

In a controller, I have access to `Server` object which I can call `Server.MapPath` and it does the magic, below I cant access to that Object since it is not a `Controller`.

How can I upload to anywhere in file system or in project root below?

```
public class FileService : IFileService
{
    private const string UploadBase = "/Files";

    public File UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (file != null)
        {
            string folder = DateTime.Today.Month + "-" + DateTime.Today.Year;

            string finalFolder = Path.Combine(UploadBase, folder);

            if (!Directory.Exists(finalFolder))
            {
               return Directory.CreateDirectory(finalFolder);
            }


            var filename = UploadFile(file, directoryInfo.Name + "/");


            var newFile = new File { ContentType = file.ContentType, FilePath = filename, Filename = file.FileName };

            return newFile;

        }

        return null;
    }
```

An error is : 
`The SaveAs method is configured to require a rooted path, and the path '9-2013/037a9ddf-7ffe-4131-b223-c4b5435d0fed.JPG' is not rooted.`

Comment: you mean you couldn't access the `Server` object  ?

Comment: If you need to map the virtual path to the physical path outside of controller, you can use [`HostingEnvironment.MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.mappath%28v=vs.90%29.ASPX) method.

Comment: `HttpContext.Current.Server`?

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek wanna write that as answer. i ll accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-stating what was noted in comments:

If you want to map the virtual path to the physical path outside of the controller, you can always use [`HostingEnvironment.MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.mappath%28v=vs.90%29.ASPX) method.